# Is there a reliable parse_str() alternatives that is not error-prone?

Tags: php, url

Is there any reliable alternative to [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function for parsing a query string?

I found it very confusing and error-prone specially when **query string is coming from an external service** (and you can't fully control it):

```
$error = "Error message";
parse_str("param1=hello&error=false"); // Overrides $error

parse_str($externalQuery);
// Which variables are setted and which not?
```

Comment: The *method* is not error prone. The way in which *you* are using it is error prone. All of your points are very clearly noted in the PHP docs. RTFM - [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary automagically creating variables is error-prone, IMHO.

Comment: Several PHP functions do this. Many of which, like `parse_str()`, are designed to do so by nature. Faulting the function seems rather silly, IMHO. I'm only suggesting you read the manual when using a function that may not behave the way *you expect*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$error = "Error message";
$output_array = array();
parse_str("param1=hello&error=false", $output_array); 
var_dump($output_array);
```

Do you really need to overwrite existing variables or to create new 'unknown' variables?

Comment: No need to overwrite existing variables, it's just an example about how that method can be error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

Pass the optional second argument to [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and it will place the values in an associative array instead of creating/overwriting variables. From the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

> If the second parameter arr is present, variables are stored in this variable as array elements instead.

You must initialize the array first. Do this:

```
$error = "Error message";
$vars = array();
parse_str("param1=hello&error=false", $vars);
echo $error . "\n";
print_r($vars);
```

which outputs:

```
Error message
Array
(
    [param1] => hello
    [error] => false
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [\GuzzleHttp\psr7\parse_query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/function-GuzzleHttp.Psr7.parse_query.html) function, which is available with [guzzlehttp/psr7](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.htm) composer package.

That worked for me - parse_str simply failed to parse some queries and returned an empty array.

It has a more modern synrax:

```
$aParsedQuery = parse_query($sQueryString, $bUrlDecode);
```

Where the second parameter is true by default.

Comment: I'd be curious to see examples of valid query strings that weren't parsed by `parse_str()`.

Comment: Cannot provide an example right now, but I had problems with strings containing upper ascii chars in a non-utf encoding, also the single quote char may cause problems. It seems very version-specific, as parse_str is built-in. 

parse_query, OTOH, parsed any of these w/o problems

Comment: By the way, Guzzle moved that function to `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Query::parse($queryString)`. The Guzzle function is very much superior to `parse_str()`, for example, in the way it parses `"F%5B0%5D.Page_10%5B0%5D.Veteran_Service_Member_First_Name%5B0%5D=John"`. `parse_str` fails to get any useful data out of that because it tries to be too crafty and build a multi-dimensional array, whereas Guzzle gives me the flat array I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the docs.  `parse_str` supports passing a 2nd parameter which will store the variables.

```
$error = "Error message";
parse_str("param1=hello&error=false", $data);

echo $error; // "Error message"
var_dump($data['error']); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to `parse_str`, and it will put the query string KV pairs in:

```
$error = "Error message";
$queryString = array();
parse_str("param1=hello&error=false", $queryString);

echo $error; //"Error message"
echo $queryString["error"]; //"false" (actually will echo "")
```